# How to Make Bootable Harddisk on Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, iso

hey everyone i just moved away from windows you can guess ,

im running Ubuntu 15.04 on my hdd located /dev/sd**a1**  on  how do i make a Linux mint Cinnamon x64 iso  bootable on my harddisk located on /dev/sd**b1**

> i cant use the tool called Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3 
>   because this is made for windows but i know this tool can do the job.

*i dont know how to use linux so can you tell me step by step what/how    to open and what/how to install*

i thank you with all respect and support

Comment: is there a confirmed working way of doing this maby the next question will be how do i make Startup Disk Creator  Show UP /dev/sdb1

Comment: Status Question unanswered

Comment: is this posstible? on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best way to do this is to download the mint .iso, and use Startup Disk Creator (pretty sure it's part of default) to create a bootable usb/cd. From there, you will install it normally, and specify to only install it on sdb1.

Comment: i already  open up Startup Disk Creator  /dev/sdb1 doesnt show up

Comment: i also used wine to install universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3  not working show only c:// drive 
i also downloaded unetbootin
and used the command on terminal 
sudo unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdc1
it works but doesnt boot the correct way its like the iso is damaged
i also tried 
unetbootin installtype=HDD targetdrive=/dev/sdc1
not working
i tried YUMI this application doesnt even start i feel like its virus
i tried lili usb creator

Comment: *correction* sudo unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdb1
sudo unetbootin installtype=HDD targetdrive=/dev/sdb1

Comment: sorry, bad explanation. Linux installations come in the form of .iso files usually. These are not the operating system per-se, but a disk image that when booted allows you to install the os. Once you have downloaded the file, you don't want it on sdb1, but on a usb that you will put it on in order to install it onto sdb1. You will need a usb to install it on.

Comment: i want it on sdb1 so i can install it on sda1 this is how i installed ubuntu from windows  now i want to install linux mint from sdb1  to sda1  because its ubuntu i dont know how on windows its easy the only way i found is unetbootin but it doesnt boot the right way so i need a beter tool